# Print multiple named columns with logic criteria

Tags: python

Pretty basic question, the two below pieces of code work... but the third gives a key error.  Is my syntax wrong?

**Works with column Shaft**

```
print(df[(df["PD Date"] == df["PD Date"].max()) & (df["Movement"])]["Shaft"])
```

**Works with column Activity**

```
print(df[(df["PD Date"] == df["PD Date"].max()) & (df["Movement"])]["Activity"])
```

**Does not work with Shaft and Activity**

```
    print(df[(df["PD Date"] == df["PD Date"].max()) & (df["Movement"])]["Shaft","Activity"])


KeyError: ('Shaft', 'Activity')
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```py
["Shaft","Activity"]
```

with

```py
[["Shaft","Activity"]]
```